# Writing multiple where clauses in Java using Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

below is code is a code i wrote to get the value of 'monthly Depreciation' when i select the row on my j Table by either mouse-clicked or key-pressed. but it only selects the first value for 'monthly depreciation' when i click on the rows or key-press.the problem i know is coming from the where statement but can't seem to get around it.

```
if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
           try{
          int row =dep_report.getSelectedRow();
          String Table_click=(dep_report.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
          String sql ="select Date_Acquired 'Date Acquired',Serial_Number 'Serial Number',"
                + " Description 'Description',Cost_Of_Acquisition 'Cost Of Acquisition',"
                + "Monthly_Depreciation 'Monthly Depreciation',Accumulated_Depreciation 'Accumulated                      Depreciation',Net_Book_Value 'Net Book Value'"
                + ",asset_update.Branch_Area 'Branch Area',Depts_name 'Department Name' ,User 'User',"
                + "Status 'Status' from items,asset_update where items.items_No = asset_update.items_No &&'"+Table_click+"'";
          pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          rs = pst.executeQuery();
          if(rs.next()){
                String add1 = rs.getString("Monthly Depreciation");
                MonthlyDep.setText(add1);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);    
        }
```

I would really appreciate the help thank you.

Comment: Can you please format your codes ?

Answer (score 0):

In your sql

```
where items.items_No = asset_update.items_No &&'"+Table_click+"'";
```

&& wont work for sql and you might need

```
where items.items_No = asset_update.items_No and items.someThing= '"+Table_click+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Java naming conventions and give proper names to things `Table_click` is a horrible variable name.

But can you describe what is in your table model in the 1st column of the selected row?

You seem to append that to your query and if it does not contain a valid SQL part, this will not work well with your statement. In a where clause you usually check a column against a value. I doubt that your table model has this written there, more likely you just have the value in your table model at this position.

Also make sure to properly use prepared statements. Never put the values directly in the SQL string you create or you create the perfect entry point for SQL injection. Assign the values instead once you have created the statement with something like this: `pst.setString(1, Table_click);`